# How can I have 1 htdocs folder and mysql instance and multiple versions of XAMPP (various platforms)

Tags: mysql, apache2, usb, xampp

So I want to put xampp on a usb flash drive. I also want to make it cross-platform (windows/mac/linux). Is it possible to have a shared htdocs folder and mysql db?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. This question belongs on http://serverfault.com
2. Yes, just point the config files of all apache/mysql instances to the same folder. You don't have to do anything special to the folder.